# Averaging Issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having a slight issue with averaging out columns in my rails app. It seems to be averaging against the two trial_id varieties instead of all the selected varieties.

For example.

```
trial_id | params[:variety_one] | params[:variety_two] |  Lint

  348    |        2300          |                      |  3.40
  348    |                      |        2555          |  5.40
```

So the above example when I call in my view that I want to list the average lint for variety_one it's giving me 4.40, which is the average of both variety_one(2300) and two (2555) when it should just list the average which is 3.40.

Controller

```
@comparison = Result.group('results.trial_id').having('COUNT(*) = 2').where(variety_id: [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]]).
   joins(:trial).where('trials.irrigated' => params[:irrigated], 'year' => params[:year]).joins(:regions).where('sites.region_id' => params[:regions])
@vone = @comparison.where(params[:variety_one]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
@vtwo = @comparison.where(params[:variety_two]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
@count = @comparison.count('DISTINCT results.trial_id')
@years = @comparison.where('results.year' => params[:year]).select('DISTINCT results.year')
@region = @comparison.where('sites.region_id' => params[:regions]).joins(:regions).group('regions.region_id').select("DISTINCT regions.name")
```

View

```
<% @vone.each do |vone| %>
<%= "%.2f" % (vone.lint/227) %></td>
<% end %>
<% @vtwo.each do |vtwo| %>
<%= "%.2f" % (vtwo.lint/227) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: WHat are you expecting for? what is the result that you want?

Comment: I'm wanting to loop the averages of lint for each vone and vtwo, but for some reason it's averaging them both together.

Comment: Don't you want to do something like `@comparison.group(:variety_one, :variety_two).average(:lint)`? That gets you a hash that has the averages for each variety, at least.

Comment: I think the problem is the the having count part of the @comparison variable. It can't separate the two results. Is there a better method of doing count?

Comment: All the count is doing is limiting your results set to cases where there are exactly two records for a given `trial_id`. I assume you want to do that, but I don't think that affects your averaging. I think the reason your averaging is failing is because you aren't grouping the records to be averaged by anything.

Comment: Thanks Steve, what do you mean by that? I need my @comparison to reference the count = 2 as I need both varieties to be referenced in the trial id. So your saying I need to group something then call the AVG?

Answer (score 1):

Here is where I see the problem is:

```
@vone = @comparison.where(params[:variety_one]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
@vtwo = @comparison.where(params[:variety_two]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
```

You've missed to include column name in `where` parameter.  Try updating it to:

```
@vone = @comparison.where(variety_id: params[:variety_one]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
@vtwo = @comparison.where(variety_id: params[:variety_two]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint')
```

Comment: Thanks Vee. I have tried this before, but I get no output in the view.

Comment: Can you check the value of `@vone`, your view should show `0.01` for `vone`.

Comment: @vone.inspect returns []